# Setting the Data within a nested datagrid programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

SubVwr.Tables[0].tbl is a table of several items, some of which require specific Trace. Those items which require trace have serial numbers assiciated with them. To handle this, I created a new window for each, where I'd like the user to input serial numbers. Some of the Data inside of the new table (dialog) should be pulled from the previous table (Subvwr). What would be the syntax here if I wanted to complete an assignment for a specific value within each row of dialog?

```
    private void requestSerials()
    {
        // needs to check for a difference. If QtyRcvd has changed, then we need to request "QtyRcvd" number of serials

        //for each row in our received order..
        foreach (DataRow row in SubVwr.Tables[0].Tbl.Rows)
        {
            // check to see if it neesd to be traced..
            if (row["TraceReq"].ToString() == "Y")
            {
                //if yes, create a serialInputDialogWindow
                SerialInputDialogWindow dialog = new SerialInputDialogWindow()
                {
                    Topmost = true
                };

                //Iterate through the dialogWindow before we display it to fill it with some necessary data.
                var itemsSource = dialog.serialtable.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
                if (itemsSource != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in itemsSource)
                    {
                        var serialrow = item as System.Data.DataRowView;

                            serialrow["PN"] = "test";     //doesn't work
                            serialrow.Row["PN"] = "test"; //doesn't work

                    }
                }
                dialog.ShowDialog();


            }
        }
    }
```

An example of similar code that works. It populates that specific column for each row as specified. I'd like to take Data from Subvwr and populate Dialog in a similar way

```
    foreach(DataRow row in SubVwr.Tables[0].Tbl.Rows)
    {
        row["DateRcvd"] = DateTime.Today;
        row["QtyRcvd"] = row["QtyPer"];
    }
```

Comment: What kind of collection is serialtable.ItemsSource? Is it a DataTable?

Answer (score 0):

The items in the `ItemsSource` are of some type. If for example `dialog.serialtable.ItemsSource` returns a `DataView`, you can cast the items to `DataRowViews` and then access any columns using the indexer:

```
foreach (var item in itemsSource)
{
    var serialrow = item as System.Data.DataRowView;
    if (serialrow != null)
    {
        var name = serialrow["ColumnName"].ToString();
    }
}
```

If it is an `IEnumerable<T>` and `T` is a `YourClass`, you cast it to this type:

```
foreach (var item in itemsSource)
{
    var serialrow = item as YourType;
    if (serialrow != null)
    {
        var name = serialRow.Property1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the code, and I follow the logic. but it's not working.

Comment: What is not working? The casting? What happens? And what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I'll post an example of working code that i'd like to emulate.